# COUNTIFS() for non-contiguous range defined as a NAME

Tags: countif, named-ranges

I have a spreadsheet that shows the name of attendees to meetings on one tab (e.g. Meeting 1 are columns E:G, Meeting 2 are columns H:J, etc...).  Each meeting has the name of the person invited, their team name and then a Yes/No for attendance.  The cells with names are assigned a defined name "MeetingAttendees" - and thus are non-contiguous.  On a second tab (first tab is labled "POC") I have the unique list of every possible invitee across all of the columns on the other tab (labled "Team Members").  I am trying to create a count to see how many meetings that person has actually attended (not just invited).
MeetingAttendees = "=POCs!$E$10:$E$30,POCs!$H$10:$H$37,POCs!$K$10:$K$42"
AttendeeDisposition = "=POCs!$G$10:$G$30,POCs!$J$10:$J$37,POCs!$M$10:$M$42"

Attempting this formula which doesn't seem to be working (I get "#VALUE!")
=countifs("MeetingAttendees",A2,"AttendeeDisposition","yes")
Joe Smith is a value in A2 and is one of the cells in the MeetingAttendees named range.

Please help.